# Flash Builder Data Passing between Split Views

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder, uisplitviewcontroller

I have a SplitViewNavigator with two split views. In one of the views I have a list and in another one I have questions. User must solve the question and when user click send button, he will see another question.

But when user click to send button in one view, how can i know this in the other view? I'm a newbie in Flash Builder and I'm searching for this for hours.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to do this.  One is through the view using bubbling events, but that way is not recommended since you're not mixing business level behaviour with UI behaviour.  I would recommend that you look at application frameworks for Flex, like [RobotLegs](http://www.robotlegs.org/) or [Parsley](http://www.spicefactory.org/parsley/) which definitely does stuff like this very easily.